# How to load different model and save the results automatically with loop in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to python...

If I have different h5 files and I name them as worki_bsj, where i is in 1:10, bs is in 3:10, both by 1.
Also, after loading these h5 files, I want to save the results automatically according to the name as well.

Here is what I tried:

```
for i in range(1,10):
   for j in range(3,10): 
      model = load_model('M1_i{}_bs_j{}.h5'.format(i))
....
      model.save('M2_i{}_bs_j{}.h5'.format(i))
```

Since I have both i and j, I don't know how to apply .format() here. Any help would be appreciated!

Best

Comment: comma separated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```py
for i in range(1,10):
   for j in range(3,10): 
      model = load_model('M1_i{}_bs_j{}.h5'.format(i, j))
....
      model.save('M2_i{}_bs_j{}.h5'.format(i, j))
```

Comment: Thanks! If I use a list instead of range(), can I use: bs = [1.3,4.5,6.7] then for  j in bs:

Comment: Absolutely, you can do that :)

Comment: I tried like this   ` lrates = [0.1,0.01,0.0005,5e-5]
batchsize = [8,12, 24, 30]
for i in lrates:
    for j in batchsize: 
        model = load_model('M1_lr{}_bs{}.h5'.format(i,j))
` but it did not go through each number in the lists, where did I do wrong?

Comment: Actualy, doing that `for i in lrates: for j in batchsize: print('M1_lr{}_bs{}.h5'.format(i, j))` works and go through each number of the list. Could you give a little more informations on what numbers you don't have?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear fo my question. I think the error is in the load_model() function, in this function, it did not load each h5.files....

Comment: Mmmh, if all files `M1_i{}_bs_j{}.h5` exist in the same directory than the script, well calling  `model = load_model('M1_i{}_bs_j{}.h5'.format(i, j))` should definitely load each model. What files have not been loaded? How do you know that it has not been loaded?